# salt can't recognize the file_roots in the config of master

Tags: salt-stack

I want to execute the following commands:

1) `salt '*' state.sls test`
(test is the name of the .sls file and its abspath is /srv/salt/test.sls)

the result is:

```
minion-10-211-55-3:
  Data failed to compile:
----------
  No matching sls found for 'test' in env 'base'
```

2)`salt '*' cp.get_file salt://hello.txt c:/new/hello.txt makedirs=True`

(the hello.txt exists in /srv/salt)

This command does not return any result, it is certainly failed.

---

I used to executed the two commands successfully, but somehow i can't do this someday. I don't remember which config i changed.

the file_roots part in master config is this:

```
file_roots:
  base:
    - /srv/salt
  dev:
    - /srv/salt-dev
```

I have been stuck in this problem for a few days.Because these two command are related to the env 'base', i think it is the problem of file_roots config. I have already checked my master config is right, and i have restarted the salt-master by service salt-master restart many times to make the config work.

Why salt still has the problem? The file_roots settings seems to be right. Does the config not work??

**Any help, direction is appreciated.
Thanks.**

---

The test.sls is:

```
run-an-exe:
  cmd.run:
    - name: c:/Salt-Minion-2015.8.8-2-AMD64-Setup.exe
```

I just want to test if salt can control a windows minion to run a .exe from a linux master. When the command is executed successfully, i can check a process named *Salt-Minion-2015.8.8-2-AMD64-Setup.exe* in the taskmanager.

OS:

master: CentOS 6.7(Final)

minion-10-211-55-3: windows 7

Answer (score 0):

1. Use the simpler modules call  `salt '*' state.apply test`
2. Make sure master and minion are the same version
3. When starting salt-master, use `sudo salt-master -l debug` to run the daemon to diagnose the problem.
4. ALWAYS VERIFY YOUR STATE file with yaml schema meta parser such as kwalify , e.g. `kwalify -m test.sls` . Yes, SLS contain syntax error(e.g. mix of tab and spaces) will spit the wrong "missing file" error.
5. For statement that fail on minion that run previously, restart the minion.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I downloaded pykwalify and it spit _pykwalify.errors.RuleError: <RuleError: error code 4: Key 'type' not found in schema rule: Path: '/'>_ when i uesd pykwalify to verify the state file. I wrote a python program to read my master config file and it did get the result i want.I think it is still the problem that salt can not recognize the env  'base' correctly. The indent of .sls file and config file is two spaces.Is it right??

Comment: @Neven.Leung : always use an editor that convert all tab to spaces. If you use tools such as kwalify, you need to specify to verify only the meta , since we don't have a schema for saltstack. That will help you to find out issues in yaml syntax , e.g.  mixing tab with spaces in indent,  a space after the attributes name.

Comment: Thanks for your advise:).